# Using Razor in subject of MailTo link (Razor ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to dynamically generate subjects in a mailTo link with a number using Razor from a html page. The Razor with the number is @Model.Number and I have been able to embed the number in the link, but not in the subject part of the link.

As in the code below, putting the Razor in the subject part of the link causes the email link to open with a subject that writes out @Model.Number literally. Putting it before the `?subject` part does allow me to embed it. Is there a way to use the @model.Number razor in the subject of an email link?

```
<a href="mailto:email@test.com?subject=Policy%20@Model.Number">@Email us</a>
```

(Please note: my question differs from other similar questions as they do not attempt to embed Razor in the subject part of a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic value `@Model.Number` needs to be escaped with brackets to prevent getting parsed as a literal string, like this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@test.com?subject=Policy%20@(Model.Number)">@Email us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
<a href='@("mailto:email@test.com?subject=Policy%20" + @Model.Number)'>@Email us</a>
```

or

```
<a href='@(String.Format("{0}{1}", "mailto:email@test.com?subject=Policy%20", @Model.Number)'>@Email us</a>
```